# Don't understand why I'm getting a SyntaxError from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm following a tutorial on creating python script to automate nmap port scanning and it gives me a syntax error when I try to enter an IP address.

This is a python3.x script on Debian Linux and I've tried researching the problem but most answers are just to use `raw_input()` from python2. Which isnt too helpful because `raw_input()` is just `input()` in python3

```py
import nmap
scanner = nmap.PortScanner()

print("Simple nmap automation tool")
print("<-------------------------------------------------->")

ip_addr = input("Ip to scan: ")
print("The IP address you entered is ", ip_addr)
type(ip_addr)

response = input(""" \nPlease enter the type of scan you want to run:
                       1.SYN ACK Scan
                       2.UDP scan
                       3.Comprehensive scan \nSelect Scan: """)
print("you have selected option ", response)

if response == "1":
    print("Nmap Version ", scanner.nmap_version())
    scanner.scan(ip_addr, "1-1024", "-V -sS")
    print(scanner.scaninfo())
    print("IP status: ", scanner[ip_addr].state())
    print(scanner[ip_addr].all_protocols())
    print("Open ports: ", scanner[ip_addr]["tcp"].keys())
```

When you type an `192.168.1.1` for `ip_addr` it tells me `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. When I type `192.168.1` for `ip_addr`, I get `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`. but when I type `192.168` it goes on without error.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you appear be running your Python 3.x script in Python 2.x.

Try:

`python3 my_script.py`

And you should see a different result. Here is an interactive example:

[image]

Here are some docs for `input()` in Python 2 and 3. The two are deceptively similar:

Python 2: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input

Python 3: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#input

In Python 3, `input()` will capture user input as a string. In Python 2 however, it will capture user input, and then evaluate the user input as a Python expression. Since the ip address you were entering is not a valid python expression, a syntax error was raised.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, When i run it in vscode it gives me a syntax error. When i run it inside of the terminal im able to enter a ip address without it giving me a syntax error.

Comment: @UnderwaterBaker in that case it sounds like your version of vscode is using the Python 2.x interpreter by default. You can change this setting if you have the Python extension installed by opening the command palette, and running the command: **Python: Select Interpreter**, and then selecting a Python 3 version.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I verified that my vscode interpreter is python 3.7.4 64-bit. I must have messed up on one of the last 4 print statements. When I comment those out it tells me thats unable to determine the route to the ip address.